# Image source resize param throwing undefined in Vue 3 vhtml

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, vuejs3

Hey everyone so I currently have a component the allows a user to dynamically insert html in a webpage. It works for the most part but when ever I try to pass an img element it break the image if the image has a resize variable in its src attribute.

The component looks like this

```
<template>
    <div class="article-body" v-html="articleContent">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       data() {
            return {
                 articleContent = '<img  src="https://img.webmd.com/vim/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/sponsored_programs/toc-breaking-barriers-mtnbc/infographic.png?resize=690px:*&output-quality=75" />'
            }
       }
   }
</script>
```

when I build and test this out I don't get any picture and when I go to view the elements in the developer tools of the browser I can see the image element is there but the src value becomes
"https://img.webmd.com/vim/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/sponsored_programs/toc-breaking-barriers-mtnbc/infographic.pngundefined&output-quality=75"
so there is a value of undefined that is added to where the resize parameter should be at. Has anyone experienced with vue 3 because in vue 2 this worked fine it was only when I migrated to vue 3 this started breaking. Any ideas and how to fix this so it doesn't add the undefined value to where the resize parameter is in the image url?

Some solutions I tried was playing around with the single and double quotation marks I thought some how that was interfering with the address. That didn't work. Then I tried to dynamically create the html with assigning the imgage url to a variable then doing something like

```
imageUrl = "https://img.webmd.com/vim/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/sponsored_programs/toc-breaking-barriers-mtnbc/infographic.png?resize=690px:*&output-quality=75",
articleContent = '',

create(){
     articleContent = `<img src=${this.imageUrl} />`
}
```

this didn't work either so I'm kinda stuck at this point

Answer (score 0):

tried two ways you mentioned in Vue SFC Playground, both works; might need to check your code syntax or try using encodeURI function wrap the image link

[link1](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

[link2](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).